# Highcharts is not responsive in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, highcharts

In node.js application I am using highcharts api for charts visualisation.The div in which the charts are present are hidden in onload.
When the onclick function is called the charts are appeared in the divs.
The onclick function contains an ajax call where I prepared the charts data from backend.

But the problem is that the charts are not responsive.it expands from the div.
How can i make this charts responsive.
There is the sample code of the onclick function I post for better understanding

```js
function showPanel(Abc_param1){
    var Abc_param2=$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
    var Abc_param3=$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate;

    Abc_param1=parseFloat(Abc_param1)

    var panel = $(this).parents(".panel");
    panel_refresh(panel);

    $("#hide_section10").hide()
    $("#hide_section11").hide()

    $("#hide_section15").hide()
    $("#footer_text").hide()
    var url = '/Abc_url?Abc_param1='+Abc_param1+'&Abc_param2='+Abc_param2+'&Abc_param3='+Abc_param3;
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'async': true,
        'type': 'get',
        'success': function (data) {
            device_chart.series = [{
                name: 'Device',
                data: [
                    { name: 'Mobile', y: data.Mobile },
                    { name: 'Desktop', y: data.Desktop },
                    { name: 'Tab', y: data.Tab }
                ]
            }]
            $("#people_read").highcharts(device_chart);
            $("#hide_section1").show();
            $("#hide_section10").show()
            $("#hide_section11").show()
            $("#hide_section15").show()


        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting minPadding and maxPadding to 0.

Answer (score 0):

In Js Code in ajax success function add

```
$("#people_read").highcharts(device_chart);
$('#people_read').highcharts().reflow()
```

And in html rendering div will be

```
<div id="people_read" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Edit**

More Explanation

> reflow ()
>   Reflows the chart to its container. By default, the chart reflows automatically to its container following a window.resize event, as per the chart.reflow option. However, there are no reliable events for div resize, so if the container is resized without a window resize event, this must be called explicitly.

[Resize div and reflow](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-reflow/) and [pop up and reflow](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/)

[From Highcharts Option Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.reflow)

Comment: I have used your suggested code but it didn't work.Actually when the onclick function is called the charts are stretched out from the div but when I press f12 twice it resize to the div and then the charts become responsive then  and if I want to set height and width as for desktop view it is not responsive in mobile.Please suggest any other alternation option to fixed it up